# How to use hyphen inside .find_all of BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, findall

I'm trying to collect the text value that is inside span, in the case called `Full Time`:

```
<div id="bottomContainer">
  <div class="tableWrapper">
    <div class="clockWrapper">
      <span data-push="clock">Full Time</span>
```

But when trying to use:

```
soup.find_all("span", data-push="clock")
```

Logically returns an error asking for a parameter in `data-push` because of the hyphen, how should I proceed in cases like this?

Comment: data-push is an expression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only use valid python variable names as names of keyword arguments, i.e. `data-push` is an expression and no valid variable name. In this case use

```py
soup.find_all("span", attrs={'data-push': 'clock'})
```

instead.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use a CSS selector:

```
print(soup.select('[data-push="clock"]'))
```