# python - beautiful soup get specific span value

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

html

```
<span class="percentage" data-qa="score1">
                                95%
                            </span>
<span class="percentage" data-qa="score2">
                                77%
                            </span>
```

code:

```
soup.find('span', class_='percentage')
```

Desire Result:

```
77%
```

Actual Results:

```
95%
```

Question

```
How do you specify the score2 value?
```

Comment: Add `data="score2"` to the `find()` call.

Comment: Have you tried using `all = soup.findAll()`, and then iterating through all the `span` matches?

Comment: @barmar - could you please share the syntax in how? thats the struggle I'm having.

Comment: ('span', class_='percentage', data='score1') I get error: SyntaxError: expression cannot contain assignment, perhaps you meant "=="?

Comment: You're missing the function call `soup.find`

Comment: @Steinn Hauser Magnusson - unfortunately if the sequence changes it will put the wrong value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `attrs` argument to specify attributes in a dictionary.

```
soup.find('span', attrs={"class": "percentage", "data-qa": "score2"})
```

See [How to use hyphen inside .find_all of BeautifulSoup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68532522/how-to-use-hyphen-inside-find-all-of-beautifulsoup)

Comment: ('span', class_='percentage', data='score2') I get error: SyntaxError: expression cannot contain assignment, perhaps you meant "=="

Comment: actually the value is data-qa='score' corrected the original question.

Comment: The odd thing is when I use "data" it returns = none but when I use "data-qa" it gives an error SyntaxError: expression cannot contain assignment, perhaps you meant "=="?.  Also, in VS code the data-qa is not hightlighted all blue just the "qa" part which is odd.

Comment: Parameter names can't have `-` in them, they have to be valid variable names.